# How can I download emails from Gmail using C#/WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, gmail

I have a project (Visual C# 2010 Express) that requires me to download my Gmail inbox in the background, then parse through them and put the ones that I need in a ListBox or something. I haven't been able to install the Google API, as it says I need .NET 2.0 and I don't know how to use NuGet. Is there a way to do this without the Google API, and if not, how can I install it?

Comment: You don't install an API, you access an API.  You can download the Google .net client library but you dont install that either.     Nuget package location is:   Install-Package Google.Apis.Gmail.v1    try and google how to use Nuget referencing all the dlls yourself will be a pain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you dont require to have Google API for getting(downloading) emails from Gmail account. You can read more about [Reading Gmail Inbox Message](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188349/Read-Gmail-Inbox-Message-in-ASP-NET)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace mail
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Imap client = new Imap();
            // connect to server

            client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, SslMode.Implicit);

            // authenticate
            client.Login("username", "password");

            // select folder
            client.SelectFolder("Inbox");

            int NoOfEmailsPerPage = 10;
            int totalEmails = client.CurrentFolder.TotalMessageCount;
            // get message list - envelope headers
            ImapMessageCollection messages = client.GetMessageList(ImapListFields.Envelope);

            // display info about each message


            foreach (ImapMessageInfo message in messages)
            {

                TableCell noCell = new TableCell();

                noCell.CssClass = "emails-table-cell";

                noCell.Text = Convert.ToString(message.To);
                TableCell fromCell = new TableCell();
                fromCell.CssClass = "emails-table-cell";
                fromCell.Text = Convert.ToString(message.From);
                TableCell subjectCell = new TableCell();
                subjectCell.CssClass = "emails-table-cell";
                subjectCell.Style["width"] = "300px";
                subjectCell.Text = Convert.ToString(message.Subject);
                TableCell dateCell = new TableCell();
                dateCell.CssClass = "emails-table-cell";
                if (message.Date.OriginalTime != DateTime.MinValue)
                    dateCell.Text = message.Date.OriginalTime.ToString();
                TableRow emailRow = new TableRow();
                emailRow.Cells.Add(noCell);
                emailRow.Cells.Add(fromCell);
                emailRow.Cells.Add(subjectCell);
                emailRow.Cells.Add(dateCell);
                EmailsTable.Rows.AddAt(2 + 0, emailRow);

            }
            int totalPages;
            int mod = totalEmails % NoOfEmailsPerPage;
            if (mod == 0)
                totalPages = totalEmails / NoOfEmailsPerPage;
            else
                totalPages = ((totalEmails - mod) / NoOfEmailsPerPage) + 1;



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this in WinForms?

Comment: Yes you can do that have a look on [Reading Mail in Windows form Using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051712/reading-mail-in-windows-form-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @AgoraStudent Does it helped you? If Yes you can accept it as answer and you can say thanks by upvoting the answer.

Comment: Does that still work I thought the client login servers where shut down?  I normally use Oauth2.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava I'm still working on it. I'll mark it answered if it helps though